# Getting data from another table, if exist will show as Yes else No

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am trying get a new column Claim_YN in a table. If there is data exists in the other table, then return 'yes' else return 'no'. Here's an example:

Product Table:

| Product_ID |
| --- |
| prod_1 |
| prod_2 |
| prod_3 |
| prod_4 |
| prod_5 |
| prod_6 |

Claim Table:

| CLAIM_PRODUCT_ID |
| --- |
| Prod_1 |
| Prod_2 |
| Prod_6 |

I would to see these 2 columns combined and gives like in the output below:-

| Product_ID | Claim Y/N |
| --- | --- |
| prod_1 | Yes |
| prod_2 | Yes |
| prod_3 | No |
| prod_4 | No |
| prod_5 | No |
| prod_6 | Yes |

So if a claim exists then the generated new column CLAIM_YN will return 'Yes', else it will return 'No'.

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks!

Comment: Which are you using, Oracle or MySQL? Don't add unnecessary tags.

Comment: In either database, use `LEFT JOIN` to determine if there's a matching row in the other table.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine a `LEFT JOIN` with a `CASE` clause. For example:

```
select
  p.product_id,
  case when c.claim_product_id is not null then 'Yes'
    else 'No' end as claim_yn
from product p
left join claim c on c.claim_product_id = p.product_id
```